# What Insights are provided on Facebook for reaching the 30 "people like" level for a page?

Tags: facebook-pages

On the Facebook "Admin Panel" there is a section "Insights" which states:

> Once 30 people like your Page, you'll get access to insights about
>   your activity.

What does this provide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It provides some statistical information about the `Like` in your page, such as total likes, trends etc [About Page Insights](http://www.facebook.com/help/336893449723054/).